# Continue loop after 404 response

Tags: go

This maybe a noob question but I've been googling for a while.

I am running in a for loop, for each loop a different api request

```
jiraClient, err := jira.NewClient(nil, *jiraURL)

if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

jiraClient.Authentication.SetBasicAuth(*jiraUser, string(jiraPass))

reader := csv.NewReader(*file)
CSVData, err := reader.ReadAll()

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}

lineCount := 1

for _, line := range data {

    //reading CSV

    //this returns 200 for all users found but 404 for not found
    user, resp, _ := jiraClient.User.Get(user) 

    if resp.StatusCode == 200 {
        fmt.Printf("Changed %s to %s\n", user.Name, data.user)
    } else {
        // have tried continue, return
    }
}
```

Every time it gets to a 404 response, the program fails and exits

I've tried a try and catch with no luck.

How can i have it continue?

Comment: There is no try/catch in Go. How are you making the GET call?  A 404 is not an error returned by Get.

Comment: ok. the one i found must have been custom then .. i've edited the command

Comment: Show a complete example, please. There is no loop at the moment. Also, what type is jiraClient? What is the return value you are ignoring? Probably an error that you can inspect and handle appropriately.

Comment: Request failed. Please analyze the request body for more details. Status code: 404

Comment: You need to show the full code.  Your question doesn't show the loop or how the error value returned is handled (or ignored).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question leaks details that because it earned so much down-votes. I assumed that we are dealing with a [Get method of UserService in go-jira.](https://github.com/andygrunwald/go-jira/blob/master/user.go#L33)

The `Get` method returns error:

```
func (s *UserService) Get(username string) (*User, *Response, error)
```

You are omitting error check and pulling it to a blank identifier. Note that if an error returned with a non-nil value then the `*User` is `nil`.

```
resp, err := s.client.Do(req, user)
if err != nil {
    return nil, resp, err
}
```

And if even I incorrectly assumed a lib which you are using it is a Go way to handle the situation. The proper way is to check error value and do what you need but not wait until your program face nil pointer dereference.

```
  user, resp, err := jiraClient.User.Get()
  if err != nil {
      // Do something clever...
  }
```

### Errors are values

Furthermore `error` is an interface. So error could contain some useful data or be an object of a concrete type.

> An error variable represents any value that can describe itself as a string. Here is the interface's declaration:

```
type error interface {
    Error() string
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info .. you're right it could've been more detailed. I figured the question was straight forward if the response is 404 then don't exit go to the next in the for loop